# safe to use relative paths ins Java?

Tags: java, path, relative-path

I have a little Java application (JRE 1.5). The user types in a path: this path could be a relative path (e.g. `./myFolder` or `../myRootFolder`).

When I create a file object from this path I receive this path:

```
C:\Programs\working_dir\.\myFolder
```

Java seems to be able to work with this: sourceDir_file.exists returns "true" for this file.

Is it safe to work with this file or should I remove `.\` from the path?

Answer (score 2):

safest way is `public URL getResource(String name)`

and relative path will be the more safest than the absolute

why because A single file existing on a `system` can have many different `paths` that refer to it